# how can I format a (large) number in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

A database call returns this json formatted data:

```
[{"expense_project_id":1,"project_id":1,"project_name":"miki project 1","item_amount":"0.7607479E5","item_count":7},{"expense_project_id":1,"project_id":2,"project_name":"project 2","item_amount":"0.7607479E5","item_count":7}]
```

I want to format the item amount so that it comes out as, for example, `21.87 I have tried this:

```
parseFloat(this["this_amount"]).toFixed(2)
```

and, in the HTML page, I get `NaN`

How can I fix it guys? Thank you.

`

Comment: What does `this["this_amount"]` contain?

Comment: Er... there is no 'this_amount' field in your JSON. Is this intentional?

Comment: I suppose it's just a typo and you don't really want to get `21.87` from `0.7607479E5` but it'd be better to edit the question and clean it up. Also, the reference to large numbers is fairly unclear: 20 can hardly be considered *large*; my 2yo daughter can already count from 1 to 12.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this `item_amount` no `this_amount`is found in ur result

```
var arr = [{"expense_project_id":1,"project_id":1,"project_name":"miki project 1","item_amount":"0.7607479E5","item_count":7},{"expense_project_id":1,"project_id":2,"project_name":"project 2","item_amount":"0.7607479E5","item_count":7}];

console.log(parseFloat(arr[0]["item_amount"]).toFixed(2));
```

Comment: sorry chaps, it was a typo. I was being very dumb. Yes, 20 is not a large number. Could be 100,00 but irrelevant anyway. I appreciate your time guys.

Answer (score 0):

To format the "item amount", change `"this_amount"` to `"item_amount"` in your code :

```
parseFloat(this["item_amount"]).toFixed(2)
```

Answer (score 0):

And your variable is an array so you should do this :

```
var arr = [{"expense_project_id":1,"project_id":1,"project_name":"miki project 1","item_amount":"0.7607479E5","item_count":7},{"expense_project_id":1,"project_id":2,"project_name":"project 2","item_amount":"0.7607479E5","item_count":7}];

console.log(parseFloat(arr[0]["item_amount"]).toFixed(2))
```